# Save a http request return value in a variable

Tags: javascript, http, callback, return, undefined

I try to get data by using http request and callback function but i get undefined when i try to print
the variable.

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

var response;
httpGetAsync("https://localhost:44319/api/Food/Get",function(result){
    response = result;
})

console.log(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try put `console.log(response)` inside callback. Right now console.log is called before http response was received.

Comment: Can i save the returned result in the response variable somehow?

Comment: @LeventeMakszimus Right now variable response is the result, but its scope is only inside function
httpGetAsync("https://localhost:44319/api/Food/Get",function(result){
    response = result;
})

So all the logic should go there, if you need to do something after you have received response from http request